# How to insert a category throgh direct database query in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I Need a solution to insert the categories directly to database with sql queries but i am unable to populate the path ,level columns value. i can populate the category table by magento ORM but is there any way we can insert the category directly to database through sql queries.

Thanks in Advance to all of you for your help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Categories directly using not a good practice it will cause issue during migration.

Please refer below link it will help in creating categories using cli scipt

http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/16/magento-import-categories-from-cli/